# Sub Query with Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, distinct

I'm trying to get the distinct Area codes so I can filter the Top 5 within a report based on a week date range each time it has run.

```
  SELECT
        [Area] AS 'AreaCode',
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gail_hazzards gh1 WHERE [gh1].[Area] = [gh].[Area]) AS 'AreaCount',
        CONVERT(DATE, gh.[Timetag1], 201) AS 'Time'
    FROM
      gail_hazzards gh

      GROUP BY gh.[Area], CONVERT(DATE, gh.[Timetag1], 201)
      ORDER BY AreaCount  DESC
```

**Results:** I have been trying to add a sub query to get the distinct Area code but I'm having issues trying to get this to come out correctly :/

```
AreaCode    AreaCount   Time
480            683     2016-03-23
480            683     2016-03-24
480            683     2016-03-25
480            683     2016-03-29
480            683     2016-03-30
870            210     2016-04-15
870            210     2016-04-16
870            210     2016-04-19
870            210     2016-04-20
870            210     2016-04-21
```

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  (2) I changed the tag from MySQL to SQL Server, based on the syntax in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Area),
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[tkg_gail_hazards] c WHERE c.Area = x.Area and CONVERT(date, c.TimeTag1, 102) >= CONVERT(date, @p_start, 102) AND CONVERT(date, c.TimeTag1, 102) <= CONVERT(date, @p_end, 102)) as 'Total' 
        FROM [dbo].[tkg_gail_hazards] x
        ORDER BY Total desc;
```

The code above along with some filters applied gave me the data as required - Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description in your question, I would expect a query to look like this:

```
SELECT [Area] AS AreaCode, COUNT(*) AS AreaCount,
        CONVERT(DATE, gh.[Timetag1], 201) AS 'Time'
FROM gail_hazzards gh
WHERE gh.Timetag1 BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY gh.[Area]
ORDER BY AreaCount  DESC;
```

I'm not sure what the "week time range" should be, but it might be something like:

```
WHERE gh.Timetag1 BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -6, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

Comment: I think I may have the question slightly confused, Your code required the TimeTag to be included into the aggregate but aside from that it helped me along :) - I decided to turn it into a stored procedure with some data variables for the filter options and TOP N applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
select AreaCode,AreaCount,Time from (SELECT row_number() over(partition by Area order by [Timetag1] desc) as RowNum,
Area as AreaCode, COUNT(*) AS AreaCount,
CONVERT(varchar, Timetag1, 103) AS 'Time'   
FROM gail_hazzards
GROUP BY Area,Timetag1) as tbl
where RowNum<6
order by AreaCode,Time
```